# Long Form words to short form

Tags: java

How can I use indexOf() and CharAt() method to show the output like that?
"B R A M"

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = new String("Business Requirement And Management");
    String shortForm = "";
    int index = 0;
    int i=0;

    while(i<s.length()) {
        if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
        index = s.indexOf(" ");
        shortForm +=  s.charAt(index+1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(shortForm);         

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s = "Business Requirement And Management";
String[] splitted = s.split("\\s");
for(String str : splitted)
{
    sb.append(str.charAt(0)).append(" ");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Explanation:**

We spilt the String at every whitespace character by calling `split("\s")` and store the new "substrings" in an array. Now iterate over the array and take the first character of each string and append it to the String.
Optionally you could use `System.out.println(sb.toString().toUpperCase())` if you want to be certain that the initials are in upper case.

Comment: Still take a look at the answer from czpona. He shows the right approach when it's necessary to use `indexOf()` (e.g. in case of an assignment etc). Otherwise i would suggest my approach ( for reasons of efficiency and readability).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = new String("Business Requirement And Management");
    String shortForm = "";
    int index = 0;

    while(s.length() > 0) {
        index = s.indexOf(" ");
        if(index == -1 || index == s.length() -1) break;
        shortForm +=  s.charAt(index+1);
        s = s.substring(index+1);

    }
    System.out.println(shortForm);         
  }
}
```

Comment: This really helps me! Thank you very much:)